# What does .php?action.. do?

Tags: php, html, forms

Can someone explain to me what is the use of `?action=add&code=` and what they do in the code below? I have tried to search it on Google but they gave me HTML action atribute instead.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
```

Sorry for the noob question.Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the url after `?` we can pass the values onto another webpage which can be used further.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe the question is asking about the "action" key in the URL query string, not the `action` attribute on the `<form>` element.

Comment: @David Oh i'm sorry i got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called query string values or parameters, they are one of several potential [parts of a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL).  Each key/value pair provides information that the server-side code can use when constructing the response to send back to the client.  (Or the server-side code could even simply ignore them, they have no harmful effect.)

For example, given this key/value pair on the query string:

```
action=add
```

In the server-side code you can get the value `"add"` by fetching it from the query string by its key:

```
$action = $_GET["action"];
// $action now contains the string "add"
```

Presumably the logic in the code would then do something based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

action is the name of a "normal" GET variable `$_GET['action']`.

You must look in the further code to see where it appears and what it is used for.

There is no standard for that